# decreasing and concavity of function

Tags: calculus

> If $g(x)=x-\sqrt{x}.$ Then the interval in which function is decressing and also find the interval in which function $g(x)$ is concave upward,is

My trial way

Dpmain of function is $x\geq 0$

$\displaystyle g'(x)=1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $\displaystyle g''(x)=\frac{1}{4x\sqrt{x}}$
For decreasing function $g'(x)<0$ and concave upward $g''(x)>0$

Function is decreasing in $\displaystyle \bigg(0,\frac{1}{4}\bigg)$ and concave upward in $x>0$

My doubt is whether we include $x=0$ in the interval or not

Means can we say function decreasing in $[0,1/4)$ and concave upward in $[0,\infty)$

Please clearfy me . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Take any interval $[0,t]$, where $t<1/4$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,t]$ and differentiable on $(0,t)$. For $x\in[0,t]$, what can you say about $g(t)-g(0)$?

Comment: So what should be the final answer. Means $[0,1/4)$ and $[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Talking about a point in context of increasing/decreasing of a function is vague. The question boils down to asking whether $g$ is decreasing at $x=0$. So one may or may not choose to write it that way, either way is correct.

Comment: And what we can say about concavity. Can we include $x=0$

Comment: I would restrain myself from including $x=0$ for interval where $g$ is concave upward. Otherwise it would be an inflection point but since the curve does not exist for $x\lt 0$, it does not satisfy the condition of being called an inflection point.

Comment: Thanks so much.